# How to get data from two tables with DjangoORM?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-orm

I have two tables in the database:

```
class CustomerEquipment(models.Model):
serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
state_timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
state_type = models.IntegerField()

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'customer_equipment'


class LogCustomerEquipment(models.Model):
    state = models.IntegerField()
    state_timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'log_customer_equipment'
```

I execute two database queries:

```
    customer_equipment_list = CustomerEquipment.objects.using('portal').filter(
        Q(state_type=10) & Q(state_timestamp__icontains='2020-02-27')
    )
    log_customer_equipment_list = LogCustomerEquipment.objects.using('portal').filter(
        Q(state=2) & Q(state_timestamp__icontains='2020-02-27')
    )
```

I need to get **serial_number** which are in both tables.
How to do it? How can I optimize queries? The same **serial_number** can be in both tables. Need to choose those that intersect.

Comment: You want a single query that gets all `serial_number`s from both tables? Do you want to only get unique values?

Comment: @Iain Shelvington - yes, unique values. Need a speed-optimal query, not necessarily one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
set(CustomerEquipment.objects.values_list('serial_number ', flat=True)) & set(LogCustomerEquipment.objects.values_list('serial_number ', flat=True))
```

or maybe you should refactor models from the relation.
For example, using ForeignKey or ManyToManyField.